# TOC Spacing in Memoir

Tags: spacing, table-of-contents, memoir

I am using memoir, and I would like to change the vertical space between entries in my toc.  This seems like a simple thing that should have been answered elsewhere, but I can't find anything that answers this directly.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Section 9, around table 9.3 in the memoir manual.

Memoir defines a number of lengths, called `\cftbeforeKskip` (where K is the name of the piece of structure concerned), as the amount of additional space before each type of entry. Thus, to add space before a subsection entry, use something like:

```
\setlength{\cftbeforesubsectionskip}{2em}
```

The defaults are zero for section and below. For book, part and chapter, the defaults are these:

```
\setlength{\cftbeforebookskip}{2.25em \@plus\p@}
\setlength{\cftbeforepartskip}{2.25em \@plus\p@}
\setlength{\cftbeforechapterskip}{1.0em \@plus\p@}
```

If you want to do something similar, in order to add glue, rather than a fixed length, in your preamble, remember to enclose them in a `\makeatletter` ... `\makeatother` pair.

Comment: This answers things perfectly.  I just failed to understand that K was a variable when I was working through the manual.

Comment: @Jeremy: Yes, I had to read it about five times, too, and then even dig into the class file, before I twigged that K was a explanation placeholder.